# How do I prevent logged in user access to @@historyview in Plone-5.X?

Tags: permissions, plone, plone-5.x

Is there a permission I can remove from a role so that the user cannot access @@historyview for Dexterity content types? I have tried "View History", "ATContentTypes: View history" and "CMFEditions: Access previous versions". The last one prevents the 'History' link from appearing on most by lines, but still leaves the "History" button in the toolbar.

The installed products on my site are:

- Content-types (plone.app.contenttypes) 1.2.16
- Dexterity versioning
  support  1.2.8

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noted the same issue recently on Plone 5.0.6.

Know that:

- `View History` is an old Zope2 permission not used by Plone in any way
- `ATContentTypes: View history` *was* the proper permission (and this permission was working as expected) but for old ATCT/Plone 4 types.

Dexterity content types is not using a proper permission for this anymore.

First: the access to the history view is public (you can call `/@@historyview` on any accessible content as anonymous). This view [call another subview](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/7a603af3ef2d387e77507e3f1f1a11e447010658/plone/app/layout/viewlets/history_view.pt#L105) (`@@contenthistory`) which is public but someway not callable.

Luckily information you'll see in the history view are protected.
The `fullHistory` of the content is composed by two history sets:

- [workflow history](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/7a603af3ef2d387e77507e3f1f1a11e447010658/plone/app/layout/viewlets/content.py#L325), which is protected by permission `Request review` *or* `Review portal content`
- [content revision history](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/7a603af3ef2d387e77507e3f1f1a11e447010658/plone/app/layout/viewlets/content.py#L398), which is protected by `CMFEditions: Access previous versions` permission

Let's recap:

- to let links disappear from Plone UI you must probably change permissions somewhere
- to let the `@@historyview` not accessible you need to override it with new a permission
- ...but you still need to take care of permissions needed for accessing history sets.

Comment: Luca,First thank you. You always seem to be answering my questions. If I understand this correctly, you are saying that there is no straightforward way to limit the access to history information without rewriting templates and some of the lower level permission checking in Plone. In my particular use case I need to protect author identities on some content items. I guess I need to figure out which viewlet template is still allowing author information to show up in the "below-content-title" byline info in the history view. I've figured out where it is coming from in all the other views.

Comment: More or less: yes. You need to override/monkey patch some behavior to add/change protection to this part of Plone. In my usecase I was not happy to the hard-coded protection of the workflow history (it's only fit default workflow and what I needed was user's not able to edit or review but able to see history) so I tried simply changing permission check I linked in my answer but I failed: other inner code probably check for the same permissions.